# Always getting deadlock with channels

Tags: go, channel

I'm learning to work with Go channels, and I'm always getting deadlocks. What might be wrong with this code? Printer randomly stops working when array sizes are unequal; I guess it would help to somehow notify printer that receiver stopped working. Any ideas how to fix it? My code is pasted below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
var wgs = sync.WaitGroup{}
var sg = make(chan int, 50)
var gp1 = make(chan int, 50)
var gp2 = make(chan int, 50)

func main(){
    wgs.Add(2)
    go Sender(0)
    go Sender(11)

    wg.Add(3)
    go Receiver()

    go Printer()
    go Printer2()

    wg.Wait()
}

func Sender(start int){
    defer wgs.Done()
    for i := start; i < 20; i++ {
        sg <- i
    }
}

func Receiver(){
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++{
        nr := <- sg
        if nr % 2 == 0{
            gp1 <- nr
        } else{
            gp2 <- nr
        }
    }
}

func Printer(){
    defer wg.Done()
    var m [10]int

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        m[i] = <- gp1
    }

    wgs.Wait()
    fmt.Println(m)
}

func Printer2(){
    defer wg.Done()
    var m [10]int

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        m[i] = <- gp2
    }

    wgs.Wait()

    fmt.Println(m)
}
// Better to use this one
// func Receiver(senderChannel <-chan int, printerChannel1 chan<- int, printerChannel2 chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sender generates (I think 28 messages) . Roughly half the first 20 of these go to one of gp1 and gp2.  Printer and Printer2 then unload the messages

Trouble is, the way that Receiver splits the messages depends on if the number received is odd or even.  But you aren't controlling for this.  If one of the Printers has less than 10 items in it's queue it will hang

That's one potential problem

Answer (score 0):

Your core problem is that everything in this is "dead reckoning": they expect to see a fixed number of messages, but this doesn't necessarily match up with reality.  You should set up the channels so that they get closed once all of their data gets produced.

This probably means setting up an intermediate function to manage the sending:

```
func Sender(from, to int, c chan<- int) {
    for i := from; i < to; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}

func SendEverything(c chan<- int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        Sender(0, 20, c)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        Sender(11, 20, c)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}
```

Make the dispatcher function work on everything in the channel:

```
func Receive(c <-chan int, odds, evens chan<- int) {
    for n := range c {
        if n%2 == 0 {
            evens <- n
        } else {
            odds <- n
        }
    }
    close(odds)
    close(evens)
}
```

And then you can share a single print function:

```
func Printer(prefix string, c <-chan int) {
    for n := range c {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %d\n", prefix, n)
    }
}
```

Finally, you have a main function that stitches it all together:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    inputs := make(chan int)
    odds := make(chan int)
    evens := make(chan int)

    wg.Add(4)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        SendEverything(inputs)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        Receive(inputs, odds, evens)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        Printer("odd number", odds)
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        Printer("even number", evens)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

The complete example is at https://play.golang.org/p/qTUqlt-uaWH.

Note that I've completely refrained from using any global variables, and either things have a hopefully self-explanatory very short name (`i` and `n` are simple integers, `c` is a channel) or are complete words (`odds`, `evens`).  I've tended to keep `sync.WaitGroup` objects local to where they're created.  Since everything is passed as parameters, I don't need two copies of the same function to act on different global variables, and if I chose to write test code for this, I could create my own local channels.